# Powershell - Group names- How to append to group name unless append already exists

Tags: powershell

I am trying to append to a group display name unless the append already exists currently my code is as below and it works on the first pass but if you re run it it appends the text each time again.

I would like a way to check if the "-Yammer" already exists in display name and skip if it does.
Any clever ways of achieving this ?

Many Thanks

```
Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize Unlimited |?{$_.GroupSku -eq "Yammer"} |  Export-Csv "C:\Temp\yammerGroup.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Import-CSV "C:\Temp\yammerGroup.csv" | ForEach-Object {
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity $_.id -DisplayName ($_.DisplayName + "-Yammer")}
{
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity $_.id -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $False}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `if statement` with the `EndsWith` method to check if the end of the group name matches your specified string.

Note `EndsWith` is case-sensitive, so I've also added `ToLower` to convert the group  name to lower-case first.

```
Import-CSV "C:\Temp\yammerGroup.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    if (! ($_.DisplayName.ToLower().EndsWith("-yammer") ) )
    {
        Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity $_.id -DisplayName ($_.DisplayName + "-Yammer")
    }
}
```